# How to import and display list of images in GUI using Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import glob, os

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

# Function to display image
def displayImg(img):
    image = Image.open(img)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    newPhoto_label = Label(image=photo)
    newPhoto_label.pack()

# gta_images = []
os.chdir("gta")
for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    # gta_images.append(str(file))
    displayImg(file)
    print(file)

# print(gta_images)    

root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to load images from a folder called "gta" and then display those game logos on my app. Program has no error but I think its a logical error. I am new to Python I don't know maybe there is some scoping logic problem in my displayImg funcion.

Comment: try saying `global photo` on top of your `displayImg(img)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: When a PhotoImage object is garbage-collected by Python (e.g.
> when you return from a function which stored an image in a local
> variable), the image is cleared even if it’s being displayed by a
> Tkinter widget.

[For more.](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import glob, os

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
photos = []

def displayImg(img):
    image = Image.open(img)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    photos.append(photo)#keep references!
    newPhoto_label = Label(image=photo)
    newPhoto_label.pack()

for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    displayImg(file)
    print(file)
   

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work but try using the path of the gta folder you are getting the images from, instead of its name simply - replace the name with the path.

Comment: this looks more like a comment, than an answer, maybe consider deleting this and posting a comment?

Comment: If you meant to leave a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), please wait until you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). cc @CoolCloud It requires 50 reputation points :)